# Input сделать картинкой

Tags: html, css

Нужно из кнопки type="submit" сделать картинку, в стилях прописываю

```
background: transparent url('img.png');
```

Как можно сделать из кнопки картинку ? Не делая type="image" потому, что так не будет работать форма.

Comment: сделайте label оберните им кнопку и вставте в него картинку, кнопку спрячьте (вроде самый универальный способ: position: absolute, left: -8000px) ну это на случай если вам  тег <button> не нравится. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/eg4EX/

Comment: с button тоже есть свои косяки

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/jxfLD/ - может так?

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type = "image" src = "src.png">
```

Примерно так.

Comment: @zooZooz, похоже, что до последнего предложения в вопросе, вам не хватило сил дочитать ;)